# find duplicates users and their activity count in list of logs in python

Tags: python, list, dictionary

I have list of logs in python like

```
[{'activity': 'eating', 'time': 800, 'user': 'A'},
 {'activity': 'running', 'time': 900, 'user': 'A'},
 {'activity': 'dancing', 'time': 805, 'user': 'A'},
 {'activity': 'eating', 'time': 1800, 'user': 'A'},
 {'activity': 'eating', 'time': 800, 'user': 'B'},
 {'activity': 'playing', 'time': 1000, 'user': 'B'},
 {'activity': 'playing', 'time': 800, 'user': 'B'}]
```

Now i need to find the activity count on the basis of users and at the end return something like

```
{'A': {'count': 4,
       'logs': [{'activity': 'eating', 'time': 800, 'user': 'A'},
                {'activity': 'running', 'time': 900, 'user': 'A'},
                {'activity': 'dancing', 'time': 805, 'user': 'A'},
                {'activity': 'eating', 'time': 1800, 'user': 'A'}]},
 'B': {'count': 3,
       'logs': [{'activity': 'eating', 'time': 800, 'user': 'B'},
                {'activity': 'playing', 'time': 1000, 'user': 'B'},
                {'activity': 'playing', 'time': 800, 'user': 'B'}]}}
```

i tried traversing all logs and find but that was quite messy
can someone suggest me better solution ?

Comment: On the basis of users? Do you want it to be sorted by count?

Comment: basically i want count of each users activities in logs. sorted on the basis of count will be added bonus

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
>>> logs = [{'user':'A' , 'activity': 'eating', 'time':'0800'},{'user':'A' , 'activity': 'running', 'time':'0900'}, {'user':'B' , 'activity': 'eating', 'time':'0800'}, {'user':'B' , 'activity': 'playing', 'time':'1000'}, {'user':'A' , 'activity': 'dancing', 'time':'0805'}, {'user':'A' , 'activity': 'eating', 'time':'1800'}, {'user':'B' , 'activity': 'playing', 'time':'0800'}]
>>> user_logs = {}
>>> for log in logs:
        user_log = user_logs.setdefault(log['user'], {})
        user_log['count'] =  user_log.get('count', 0) + 1
        user_log.setdefault('logs', []).append(log)


>>> user_logs
{'A': {'count': 4, 'logs': [{'time': '0800', 'user': 'A', 'activity': 'eating'}, {'time': '0900', 'user': 'A', 'activity': 'running'}, {'time': '0805', 'user': 'A', 'activity': 'dancing'}, {'time': '1800', 'user': 'A', 'activity': 'eating'}]}, 'B': {'count': 3, 'logs': [{'time': '0800', 'user': 'B', 'activity': 'eating'}, {'time': '1000', 'user': 'B', 'activity': 'playing'}, {'time': '0800', 'user': 'B', 'activity': 'playing'}]}}
```

Here is probably a better (more simple) way of doing it:

```
>>> user_logs = {}
>>> for log in logs:
        user_logs.setdefault(log['user'], []).append(log)


>>> user_logs
{'A': [{'time': '0800', 'user': 'A', 'activity': 'eating'}, {'time': '0900', 'user': 'A', 'activity': 'running'}, {'time': '0805', 'user': 'A', 'activity': 'dancing'}, {'time': '1800', 'user': 'A', 'activity': 'eating'}], 'B': [{'time': '0800', 'user': 'B', 'activity': 'eating'}, {'time': '1000', 'user': 'B', 'activity': 'playing'}, {'time': '0800', 'user': 'B', 'activity': 'playing'}]}
```

The count is no longer a key but you can get the count like so

```
>>> len(user_logs['A'])
4
```

Comment: Thanks jamylak that was very helpful but just another question on this. how can i access users A's all logs in given dictionary if I dont exactly know the name ? so let say i have 1000 users and i dont know the name/id of users, which means i cant access them like this "user_logs['A']" 
could there is another way, so that i can access it like user_logs[0] which gives me logs of user 1 which ever he is ?

Comment: @MHZ Why would you need to do this?

Comment: i need it because i dont have list of all users and on front end i need to draw a graph on the bases of user.

Comment: @MHZ does it need to be in order of name or anything?

Comment: i am extremely sorry for not sending my message go through correctly. I dont have list of users. users can be AA, ABC blah blah and that list i dont have. so your solution is really helpful but at the end i need to have username before hand to get logs of that user. all i need is that user:A remain in key value pair rather than a key for answers

Comment: @MHZ so you can just iterate through the dictionary? `for user in user_logs` Putting it back into key value pair would take extra time and I still don't understand the reason for it.

Comment: thanks jamylak i have accepted the answer but i would be grateful if you suggest me how to print count of each user in a loop

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
>>> users = {}
>>> for i in logs:
    name = i['user']
    if name not in users:
        users[name] = []
    users[name].append(i)
```

To get the output that you want:

```
... the stuff above ...
>>> for user in users:
    users[user] = {'count': len(users[user]), 'logs':users[user]}
```

Or if you want only one loop:

```
>>> for i in logs:
    name = i['user']
    if name not in users:
        users[name] = {'count':0, 'logs':[]}
    users[name]['count'] += 1
    users[name]['logs'].append(i)
```

Comment: Thanks Schoolboy. this was helpful as well i dont have enough reputation else i would have upvote your answer as well

Answer (score 0):

Use [itertools.groupby](http://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.groupby) with key as [operator.itemgetter('user')](http://docs.python.org/2/library/operator.html#operator.itemgetter) to group the elements and then iterate through the groupby object and determine the count based on length of the group

Comment: Thanks for reply abhijit. I am new with python so do you mind helping me some code ?